# iptables -D POSTROUTING -t nat -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

Tags: iptables

I was wondering if somone could explain what the purpose of MASQUERADE is. This rule is added and deleted as my openvpn connection goes up/down.

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

In addition, I would like to add a rule that disables and enables all outbound traffic, what would be the best approach for this?

Edit:

Sorry I did not provide many details. This for my router (dd-wrt (busybox)). I would like to block all outgoing traffic to prevent connections when there is no vpn connections. I would like to still enable incoming connections to the router itself so I can use web gui/ssh etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MASQUERADE is iptables' NAT option.  To quote [RedHat's customer portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html):

> Accepting forwarded packets via the firewall's internal IP device
>   allows LAN nodes to communicate with each other; however they still
>   are not allowed to communicate externally to the Internet. To allow
>   LAN nodes with private IP addresses to communicate with external
>   public networks, configure the firewall for IP masquerading, which
>   masks requests from LAN nodes with the IP address of the firewall's
>   external device.

Edit in response to your comment:

Try something like

```
:INPUT DROP
:OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.0.0/24 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.0.0/24 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

(Assuming 192.168.0.0/24 is your internal LAN;  edit as necessary.)

Comment: This is for a firewall rule on my router. I would like to be able to SSH in to my router, but I should not be able to SSH to the outside world. I should be able to access the web gui of the router but should not be able to access the outside world via port 80 or otherwise.

Comment: Aha.  Yes.  That makes more sense.  ;)  Hang on...

Answer (score 1):

1. MASQUERADE is needed for forwarding packets between instances in the network.  It allows public & private instances in your network to communicate.
2. How about a simple policy change?  In you `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` file:

*filter
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP

to drop all traffic (INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT respectively)

```
*filter  
:INPUT ACCEPT  
:FORWARD ACCEPT  
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

to allow all traffic

Comment: I think that you mean drop in the first block, rather than accept.